# Is it possible to filter files during repository conversion from SVN to Mercurial?

Tags: svn, mercurial

we are planning to convert our SVN repo to Mercurial one. The problem is that we have a lot of crap in the old one - hundreds MB of jars, exes etc. which we would like to not have in Mercurial repo, not even in history (because it would make initial clones very slow because of large size).

Neither SVN, nor Mercurial have the possibility to remove files from repository completely - you can delete it but it stays in your repo as a history.

I thought that theoretically it could be possible to just filter these files during conversion - simply convert all files except files with certain extension (.jar, .exe).

Alternatively, it would be great if hg convert would convert only files which are not removed from trunk at the time of conversion.

Naively, after running hg convert I tried to delete relevant files from .hg/store but that resulted in "abort: empty or missing revlog for ..." during push.

Did anybody tried something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: "delete relevant files from .hg/store" was big mistake, you had to use Mercurial command

Comment: I knew there was little chance it would work but there was no harm in trying it. If I would use Mercurial command, files would still stay in repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `--filemap` option to `hg convert`:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--filemap

You can also use `--filemap` for converting with hgsubversion - here's are a couple of useful pages:

http://makandracards.com/evgeny-goldin/5877-converting-svn-to-mercurial-using-hgsubversion
http://dd9e.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/using-filemap-with-hgsubversion.html